# Delete Existing iPhone App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an iPhone app that now needs to be removed. I can do this by following the steps in iTunes connect:

1. Untick all territories in pricing and availability
2. Then in Additional Information : Delete App

I have completed step 1 and am about to follow step 2 but I have a question that I cannot find answered on any of their help/docs nor online elsewhere. Once I delete the app - it will get removed from the app store, but will it still stay on all users iPhones that have already got the app downloaded and installed on their phone? Or will it automatically be deleted/removed from all phones?

Ideally I need to remove the app completely so that it can no longer be used be new or existing users even if they already have it on their phone.

Comment: It will stay on any devices that already have it installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will stay on the user's phones.

In your case even worse for you: If they backed up/synchronized the application LOCALLY via iTunes, they got a local .ipa-file (an instance of your app), which they could even restore, after they setup the device once again.

For the users this is a pretty convenient way. So, if you want to delete your application. Inform users about that step and if you have a good exit strategy, users will adopt this and will delete it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

The app will stay on the users IPhones. There is no way to remove it remotely.

The only thing you could do would be to release new version with a lock but then you will probably get trouble with Apple.